# Is there a way how I can use a VPN without interrupting current network applications?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I'm in a lab with extremely prohibitive networking policy. All traffic outwards must be through a http proxy.

Also I there's a vpn set up to our firm. I have to use the vpn for nearly all communication (email) and also other tools like to download packages for maven.

Unfortunately for most my work I need to be connected to local databases.

At the moment I have to wrap up my local work and save all before I connect to the vpn for any task as little it may be.

So my question is - is there a way how I could use the vpn to do my stuff quickly without interruting the local network applications?

(at the time I'm using a Windows XP machine, vpn is connected through Cisco AnyConnect, I can install applications as admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install your favourite virtualization software, and use the VPN from within a virtual machine.

Comment: oh clever idea!

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature of Cisco's ASA (which is what your Anyconnect client is connecting to) which allows "split tunnel". This allows traffic destined for non-local networks to be forced through the vpn, but the local subnet (and possibly other networks) to be accessed without going through the vpn.

This is considered less secure and most enterprises do not allow split tunnel.  You may ask your system administrator to request it.

Comment: (rant on) Unfortunately we are having "communication issue". I already pointed out the shortcommings of the current setup. But these requests are ignored / actively blocked. Actually my group considers setting up a second machine as our private proxy. Unfortunatly this will not be ready for a few(?) months. (rant off)

Comment: So basically the question would be what can I do locally?